# Where does the Azure ML profiler run?

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Where does the model profiler run in Azure ML?

The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-and-where#profilemodel) here explains how to register a dataset, specify the inference configuration (scoring script and environment) and run the profiler.

I am trying to profile a tensorflow model and I get this error, which essentially tells nothing about what went wrong:

```
{
    "name": "tf-profiler-experiment3",
    "createdTime": "2020-05-11T18:19:46.827933+00:00",
    "state": "Failed",
    "requestedCpu": 3.5,
    "requestedMemoryInGB": 15.0,
    "requestedQueriesPerSecond": 0,
    "error": {
        "code": "ModelProfilingJobFailed",
        "statusCode": 500,
        "message": "An internal server error occurred. Please try again. If the problem persists, contact support",
        "details": []
    }
}
```

So where exactly are 3.5 CPUs and 15 GB requested? And where to find the details of the error?